# Extract element attribute using Selenium/Python in webpage

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

Pink stuff is the email I have to derive from the webpage
black/blue stuff is confidential
using py3.6 and s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *pink* stuff refers to the *`href`* and *`title`* attributes.

To extract the *href*:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@automation-id='cpd-email-href']"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

To extract the *title*:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@automation-id='cpd-email-href']"))).get_attribute("title"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @DebanJB thank you. because this page has multiple 'email addrsses' in the same page, your solution only pulled the FIRST 1 in the page. I want what appears to be teh 2nd email, though in a different instance, it could be the 4th or 5th....

What do I do to seperate between these different 'title' values?

Comment: @TheFemaleHessian In that case you have to locate the single parent of all the descendents having the _email addrsses_ element and then identify the unique one (your desired element) based on it's unique attributes or position. However, I have changed the code a bit. Let me know the status.

Comment: Or you can wrap (xpath)[index] for it if they are all alike.